# WPF TreeView Databinding to subset of XML

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, data-binding, mvvm

Preface this by saying I am relatively new to WPF.

So basically I am getting the following XML and I need to bind everything at the tree element and below to a TreeView.  Is there a simple way of binding a specific XML element to a TreeView?

```
<Diff>
    <Packages
        left="c:\foo\foo"
        right="c:\bar\bar" />
    <Section name="Filesystem" state="different">
        <Tree>
            <Node name="VFS" state="different">
                <Node name="Windows" state="different">
                    <Node name="System32" state="different">
                        <Leaf name="notepad.exe" state="left-only" file="VFS\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" />
                        <Leaf name="cmd.exe" state="same" />
                    </Node>
                    <Node name="WinSxS" state="same">
                        <Leaf name="foo" state="same" />
                    </Node>
                </Node>
                <Node name="ProgramFilesX86" state="different">
                    <Leaf name="foo.exe" state="different" />
                    <Node name="Bar" state="right-only" >
                        <Leaf name="bar.exe" state="right-only" file="VFS\ProgramFilesX86\Bar\bar.exe" />
                    </Node>
                </Node>
            </Node>
        </Tree>
    </Section>
    <Section>
        <!--Another tree-->
    </Section>
</Diff>
```

Also not sure whether this matters, but note that there could be multiple section elements, each with a tree below it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [an `XmlDataProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.aspx) to bind the control to the XML, you should be able to set [the `XPath` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.xpath.aspx) to filter the results.

```
<XmlDataProvider 
   x:Key="FilesystemXmlData"
   Source="source.xml"
   XPath="Section[@name='Filesystem']/Tree" 
/>
```

You can then use [a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx) to bind your data to the tree.

There's a simple example in [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/317766/Displaying-XML-in-a-WPF-TreeView).